# Food diary as diagnostic aid

Tags: nutrition, pathophysiology

If I was interested in cataloguing eating habits for the purpose of shedding light on what seems to be a bowel disorder or dysfunction caused primarily, but not exclusively, by ingested food (or the ingredients from which said food is made), what information would I want to record in order for my dataset to be useful for anything?

So far I am recording timestamp for each meal, what each meal consists of (base ingredients and estimated amount where possible), and to the extent that it is practical, the reaction to each specific meal.